# FileSystemWatcher within .NET MVC Deployed Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

The code below sits in the Global.asx file within my ASP.NET MVC 5 project.
It runs perfectly and detects the file changes when debugging and running through the IDE but when published to an IIS server nothing runs.

Any ideas on how to get this started? I assumed as its in the application start that it would run automatically when deployed.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/FTP/");
    logs.WriteLog(watcher.Path);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    watcher.Filter = "*.csv";
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                 NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                 NotifyFilters.FileName |
                 NotifyFilters.DirectoryName; ;
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);


    //new watcher for Invoice PDF Files Implement Here
    FileSystemWatcher PDFwatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    PDFwatcher.Path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/FTP/PDF/");
    logs.WriteLog(PDFwatcher.Path);
    PDFwatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    PDFwatcher.Filter = "*.zip";
    PDFwatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                 NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                 NotifyFilters.FileName |
                 NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    PDFwatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(PDFDateStamp);

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The identity of the appdomain does have permission for that folder?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using Windows Authentication as its an internal application so no Identity.

Comment: The path you log with logs.WriteLog does indeed exist, right?

Comment: Debug it **locally** hosted on IIS. When running in IIS integrated mode (the default), certain features are not initialized at startup. I suspect this might have something to do with it.

Comment: @rene Nope. Logs don't write either for this part of the application.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Yes. Seems like the application_start function doesn't run when deployed

Comment: Write to the eventog of the server and ask your system engineer to hand you the result.

Comment: Event log not showing anything

Comment: Interesting that no one is questioning the general approach here so far. The Web Application is (at least in IIS, and by default) not an application guaranteed to run permanently. It can be suspended to save resources, you could also have multiple instances ("_Workers_") running with each attempting to watch the Directory etc... Your assumption ("I assumed as its in the application start that it would run automatically when deployed") is not correct. My suggestion would be to run an independent application (e.g., Windows Service, Standalone Application etc.) to cover this kind of tasks.